# Eclipse GUI shows newly styled button incorrectly

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm starting with a fully working app, with all the buttons in the right locations and the right sizes... but now I wanted to try out using styles for the first time. In particular I wanted to have the text colour in my buttons a dark blue and the background white. So I wrote the following in styles.xml in res/values ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

   <style name="mybut"  parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dblue</item>
         <item name="android:background">#ffffffff</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I modified my button code as follows:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/spec"
        style="@style/mybut"  <-- I added this line here
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.12"
        android:text="@string/spec" />
```

In eclipse's XML viewer, the new button looked right in every way. But then at run time, on my android device, the button's height had shrunk by about a third! Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I'm not very confident about the `parent="@android:style/Widget.Button"` bit. I'm suspicious that perhaps I'm somehow already using some other style?/theme? and perhaps the line should look something akin to `parent="@android:otherstyle/Widget.Button"` or `parent="@android:style/other.Widget.Button"`... or similar.

**EDIT:** FYI... I'm trying this out on a kind of "home screen" activity which just contains two big buttons. I added the `style="@style/mybut"` to just one of the two buttons. They are now clearly very different sizes.

**EDIT:** I noticed that in the manifest I have `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` ... does that mean I need to make my button's parent `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen.Widget.Button"` ?? or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a `Button` has a 9-patch background, not a simple color. This image has padding and a content area which alters the actual size of the button.

When you change the background, you're stripping that padding, and it appears smaller. The correct way to do this is to create a new 9-patch, based on the old, but with the colors changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be here:

```
  android:layout_weight="0.12"
```

If you have an action_bar or something like that when you run your app the button is going to shrink. In your preview the action_bar doesn't appear (I'm just guessing).

**EDIT**:
Here is a sample of a custom button that I use in my app, I put a min height and width.
Instead of using: `parent="@android:style/Widget.Button"` I use: `parent="android:Widget.Button"`

```
<style name="ButtonCustom" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_default_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the height change (30%?) is too drastic for that to be the issue.

Comment: @Mick I edited the answer, can you try this solution?